# Exact value for energy level impossible

Tags: energy, electrons, atoms

In order to take an electron out of a certain energy level in an atom, that electron must absorb a photon with an exact value of energy corresponding to that specific level. How is this possible given the fact that this would require infinite precision ? For example, an electron might require 10.12345eV, but a photon might have 10.123456789eV.

So how does any interaction ever takes place ?

Answer (score 1):

One does not need infinite precision, I believe due to energy-time uncertainty. You cannot determine the frequency of a wave if it only lasts a finite time. See [Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) for the transition rate.

But there are examples of extremely narrow resonances, see the [Mößbauer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_effect).